# Visual Studio Color Scheme

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019

So I updated my Visual Studio to the latest version today, and when I'm writing in C#, all the functions and variables are just white in color.
I'm so used to seeing functions in yellow and variables/properties in blue, so I would like to know if it's possible to get the colors back?

[image]

Comment: VS has rudimentary colouring available.  Check out the **Tools.Options** menu then **Fonts and colours** tab.  Resharper extends the colouring available, were you using that before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In VS 2019, go to **"Tools" > "Options" > "Text Editor" > "C#" > "Advanced"** and make sure in section **"Editor Color Scheme"** VS 2019 is selected.

**Edit**: looks like they changed the options there in an update. I remember that in this options-section in an earlier VS2019 version there was a switch named **"Use enhanced colors for C# and Basic"**

Comment: Thank you it was set to VS 2017 for some reason, I changed it to 2019 and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

As [johnmoarr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13804454/johnmoarr) suggested, try changing the default Color Scheme of the editor.

If that won't work, you can still apply colors for any element by hand. Therefore open `Visual Studio`, go to the `Tools`-menu and open the menu-item `Options`.

[image]

Within the `Options` window open `Environment` and then `Fonts and Colors`. Locate the `User Members` and `User Types` within the list of display items just like I did in the following example:

[image]

Apply the desired color to the items foreground or background. Example: set `item foreground` to white for `User Members - Methods` to display method names with white color:

[image]

Comment: Hi there sorry for the late reply. Thank you so much for helping me out! I didn't need to follow this, because my color scheme was set to VS 2017 after the update for some reason.